# Docker: Host cant connect to exposed ports and Container cant reach Internet

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, docker-compose, docker-container

I am trying to install a basic docker installation with portainer. This isnt my first time going through the installation and I already have an working installation on my home linux server.

After installing portainer I figured that the admin panel isnt available, after digging deeper I figured that the bridge system or docker0 interface isnt working at all.

My first attempt was to figure if a firewall etc is the problem. Therefore I exposed the used ports as well as tested accessing simple webserver via nginx over the same port (running without docker). To double check I also tried to curl the url locally on my server:

```
curl localhost:8080 
=> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
=> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

After that I tried accessing the port via curl directly within the docker container console, where I got an valid answere.

So after doing some reseach I figured that this article discribes pretty much my problem: https://bobcares.com/blog/connection-reset-by-peer-docker-error/
While explaining the problem very detailed I cant really figure the solution they are trying to suggest, as well as I dont know how to bind my webservers to 0.0.0.0 in various containers e.g. vaultwarden, portainer, nextcloud.

As on the mentioned website suggested I tried to expose the docker container within the host network, which worked perfectly fine: my nginx website was displayed within the localhost aswell as reachable from my domain/ip.

While the host network works perfectly fine my problem now is that I want to have multiple webservers active which are then directed by an nginx client. If I understood the host network correctly that isn't no longer possible because each webserver tries to secure the same port e.g. 80.

Another possible reason I found was during this video: https://youtu.be/5grbXvV_DSk?t=224
The video suggests to check the docker0 interface by using `ip a | grep docker0`, while there are many elements listed in the video as well as the state UP on my server the output looked a bit diffrent:

```
Server (not working)
ip a | grep docker0
=> 3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default

Home PC (working)
ip a | grep docker0
=> docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
6: veth7488899@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
8: vethad6ade9@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
```

Oddly the Server instance doesnt even have the inet line, which (if I understood correctly) should be automatically initiated.

Thanks for helping me out, System infos are below:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.0
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        98fdcd7
 Built:             Mon May 15 18:49:22 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.0
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       1331b8c
  Built:            Mon May 15 18:49:22 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Also already tried reinstalling my Image, and using the latest docker version 24.0.2 (24.0.0 only used because this version worked on my home pc)

Server specs:
Ubuntu 22.04 (freshly installed)
32 GB Ram
8 VCores
1TB Disk
(Virtual Private Server)

Comment: I also now figured that the docker container e.g. nginx cant cant connect to the internet. What I tried:
`docker exec -it nginx bash
`Within the container console:
`curl google.com
=> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.de`